# Puerto Rico Tax on Pension Income

Tags: united-states, taxes, pension, fixed-income, puerto-rico

I am considering purchasing a permanent residence in PR.  I am retired.

Based on my 3 sources of income below, what would be taxable in PR?

- Primary - pension from NYS government not subject to NYS income tax. Subjected to US Federal income tax.
- Secondary - Social Security (I understand that is not taxable in PR)
- Tertiary - RMD from a deferred compensation plan (less than $10k/year).